# Highcharts guage stop datalabels animations only

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

How can i stop data labels animation , as it decrease from 1000 it adjust its position with animation, but i don't want the animation. Here is a code for datalabels.

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
  dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
    color: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 0,
    y: 10
  }
},
```

Here is a link [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c14dns2h/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add animation false to

```
chart: {
    ..., 
    animation:false
}
```

and to

```
plotOptions: {
    ...
    gauge {
         ...,
         animation: false
    }
```

see full working fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/c14dns2h/3/

to only stop the label animation add alignment for the text and adjust your x-axis

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      ...
      x: -15,
      align: 'left'
    }
  },
```

full fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/c14dns2h/4/

Comment: ,but it also stop the animation of the needles.

Comment: i added another fiddle which just stops the label animation